# How can I improve the performance of ngx-datatable with large volumes of records?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, http, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ngx-datatable to load large volumes of records. However, the larger the volume, the longer it takes. I read somewhere that you can speed it up by sorting then assigning it to the data source. Could someone please assist me with finding the best way to improve the performance of this process?

`recipient.component.html`

```
</ngx-datatable><ngx-datatable
    #table
    class='data-table'
    [columns]="columns"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="37"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="38"
    [reorderable]="false"
    [limit]="7"
    (activate)="onActivate($event, editContent)"
    [rows]='getRecipients()'>
</ngx-datatable>
```

recipient.component.ts

```
recipients: Recipient[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.deleted_recipients = [];
    this.adhoc.getAdhocDetails(this.adhocForm.get('create.campaignNo').value).subscribe(
      x => this.seedRecipients(x),
      err => this.general.error(err)
    );
  }

    seedRecipients(csvRecordsArr: Recipient[]) {
          for (let y = 0; y < csvRecordsArr.length; y++) {
            const recipient = csvRecordsArr[y];
            recipient.status = this.getStatus(recipient);
            this.recipients.push(csvRecordsArr[y]);
          }
          this.recipients = [...this.recipients];
          this.origRecipients = JSON.stringify(this.recipients);
          this.checkStatus();
        }

getRecipients(): Recipient[] {
      return this.recipients;
    }
```

service.ts

```
getAdhocDetails(campaignNo: string): Observable<Recipient[]> {
        return this.http.get<Recipient[]>(this.baseUrl + 'getAdhocDetails/' + campaignNo).map(res => res);
      }
```

API class

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AdhocRewardInfo>> getAdhocDetails(string CampaignNo) {
                 //this._context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(200);
                 var details = await _context.AdhocRewardInfo.Where(e => e.CampaignNo == CampaignNo).ToListAsync();
                

 return details;
         }
```

Comment: Should it be on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @Elikill58 I never knew about this, thank you

Comment: No problem :) and yes i think they will be more precise on code review's se

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.